# How to prevent my users downloading firebase realtime database as a json file

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a simple search data app which give corresponding result of user input value.
My users can download firebase realtime database as a single file by going to `https://test.firebaseio.com/data.json`. How to prevent this. Any way to give search result only without reading as a full data. I mean dont allow to download full json file to user but allow to search only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)? You can set `.read` to `false` at root node so no one would be able to read it.

Comment: If I set `.read` to `false`, can my users search for it in the app? I need to allow that data in search results

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database and security rules? You can allow read only on nodes that should be public

Comment: updated in question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the `https://test.firebaseio.com/data.json` URL is using the REST API of the Firebase Realtime Database. Given the nature of a cloud-hosted database, in general people will always be able to get any data through this API that they can also access in your application code.

In fact, in a well written application the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) of your database will match closely with the client-side code of that application. For example: if you application code only reads specific keys, your security rules should only allow those keys to be read - and reject reads of other data. This is known as the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and is key to a security strategy on Firebase.

For more on this, I recommend reading some of my answers to these recent questions:

- [Firebase Realtime database - insecure rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612460/firebase-realtime-database-insecure-rules/69617781#69617781)
- [Google keeps warning insecure rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336771/google-keeps-warning-insecure-rules/69339984#69339984)

Or these older but highly ranked answers:

- [Firebase email saying my realtime database has insecure rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392059/firebase-email-saying-my-realtime-database-has-insecure-rules/51393449#51393449)
- [Firebase Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied/37404116#37404116)

---

Finally, to restrict access to the database to just your application code, consider implementing [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check). While it is not foolproof, using App Check reduces the abuse on your project by making it harder for malicious users to run their own code against your project.

Comment: Suppose the application search for `key4` and display all key values as search result in that block of json(key1 to 5) that matches user input againt `key4`, is it possible to prevent download of whole database using principle of least privilege. The whole database is array of key 1 to 5 only

Comment: Quite a few things are possible in security rules, typically much more than folks expect. If you want to only allow reading  nodes matching a specific query, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules. I recommend starting in the documentation and the links I provided, and seeing how far you can already get with securing the database to only allow what you code needs. If you are stuck at a specific use-case, post a question with the code, JSON and rules, so we can have a look.